# RSpecの特定のテストの時にだけbinding.pryで動作を確認する

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails, rspec

RSpecのテスト中に`binding.pry`で変数の状態などを確認できるように`pry-byebug`を入れて使ってみたのですが、`binding.pry`を入れておいたメソッドが複数のテストから呼ばれていると、そのテストのたびに全て止まってしまい、何度も`exit`を入力しなければすべてのテストを終えれませんでした。

特定のテストでだけ`binding.pry`を有効にするにはどうすればよいのでしょうか？

以下に例を示しておきます。

#### Classファイル

```
class Post
  def foo
    binding.pry
    # do something
    return nil
  end

  def bar
    # foo を呼び出して何かする
  end
end
```

#### Specファイル

```
let(:post){ Post.create }

describe ".foo" do
  it do
    expect(post.foo).to be nil
  end
end

describe ".bar" do
  it do
    expect(post.bar).to be 1
  end
end
```

この時に一つ目のテストでは`binding.pry`で止まるけども、2つ目のテストでは止めずに処理を続行させたいと思っています。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

特定のテストだけを実行するとよいのではないでしょうか。

```rb
describe ".foo", focus: true do
  it do
    expect(post.foo).to be nil
  end
end
```

このように`focus`でタグ付けすることで、`focus`でタグ付けされたテストのみを実行することが出来ます。

参考: [inclusion filters - Filtering - RSpec Core - RSpec - Relish](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/3-1/docs/filtering/inclusion-filters)

また、コマンドラインでRSpecを実行する際にファイル名の後ろに`:`で区切って行番号を指定することで、その行のexampleのみを実行することも出来ます。

```console
$ rspec spec/foobar_spec.rb:3
```

参考: [line number appended to file path - Command line - RSpec Core - RSpec - Relish](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/3-1/docs/command-line/line-number-appended-to-file-path)

あるいは次の様な設定を追加して`pry_debug`でタグ付けしたテスト以外では`binding.pry`をstubするとよいのではないでしょうか。

```rb
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.before do |example|
    unless example.metadata[:pry_debug]
      allow_any_instance_of(Binding).to receive(:pry)
    end
  end
end
```

```rb
describe ".foo", pry_debug: true do
  it do
    expect(post.foo).to be nil
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3):

Seiei Higaさんの回答に便乗しますが、pryを無効化する場合は `ENV['DISABLE_PRY'] = 'true'` のようにすると良いみたいです。

なので、こんな感じにするとうまくいくかもしれません。

```rb
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.before do |example|
    ENV['DISABLE_PRY'] = example.metadata[:disable_pry] ? 'true' : nil
  end
end
```

```rb
let(:post){ Post.create }

describe ".foo" do
  it do
    expect(post.foo).to be nil
  end
end

describe ".bar", disable_pry: true do
  it do
    expect(post.bar).to be 1
  end
end
```

実際には試していないのでうまくいかなかった場合は悪しからず。。。

参考文献

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8015531/how-do-i-step-out-of-a-loop-with-ruby-pry

Comment: `DISABLE_PRY`知りませんでした！便利ですね。

Comment: ありがとうございます。ただ、実際は外したいものが多数ありましたので一つ一つ除外していくよりも Seiei Higaさんの`focus: true`を用いる方法を使わせてもらおうと思います.